# Run-time error ‘5’ invalid procedure call or argument: locate Specific text using Find/ extract characters after first 16 characters using

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA Coding. I have used 3 different types of codes that are near to what I am trying to accomplish, but keep getting errors. Could someone suggest what is wrong?

In column (3) the following cells change ProfitCenterName & CouponTypes, I have Dim the variables as Strings. I named ranges for the variables to find location.

I used ProfitCenter that would located the “Closed Date/Time” since this variable name never changes, but the names of the coupons and Profit Centers do.

I search for “Closed Date/Time” using offset to locate and extract names from strings of text using “Right and lens” and then offset to place the extracted names and to delete original strings using a loop.

I also would like to place the extracted names alongside the actual transactions, but do not know how to do.

```
ProfitCenter     Coupontype 
                                    **Profit Center : Copper Oak(6)**
                                    **Coupon : 20 Yards $25(303)**
                                    Closed Date/Time
Copper Oak(6)   20 Yards $25(303)   09/27/2015 18:15
Copper Oak(6)   21 Yards $25(303)   09/27/2015 20:04
                                    Coupon Total
                                    Coupon : Dells Deals 10%(247)
                                    Dells Deals 10%(247)    
                                    09/27/2015 18:15
                                    Coupon Total
                                    Profit Center Total
                                    **Profit Center :  High Stakes Bar(2)**
                                    **Coupon : SILVER $5(298)**
                                    Closed Date/Time
 High Stakes Bar(2) SILVER $5(298)  10/24/2015 16:44
 High Stakes Bar(2) SILVER $5(298)  10/24/2015 16:44
 High Stakes Bar(2) SILVER $5(298)  10/24/2015 16:44
```

And the code:

```
Sub CopyDataFrCellAndPlaceInCellNext()

Dim ProfitCenterName As String
Dim ProfitCenter As Range
Dim Coupontype As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim CouponName As String

'In column (3)I want to select ProfitCenterName cell "Profit Center : Copper Oak(6)"
'extract only the name of the ProfitCenterName "Copper Oak(6)"
'Then place the ProfitCenterName "Copper Oak(6)" into Column(1)
'delete the original cell in column(3)"Profit Center : Copper Oak(6)"

With ActiveSheet.Columns(3)

      Set ProfitCenter = Cells.find(What:="Closed Date/Time", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
        ProfitCenterName = Right(ProfitCenterName, Len(ProfitCenterName) - 16)

            If Not ProfitCenter Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = ProfitCenter.Address

                Do
                    ProfitCenter.Offset(-2, 0).Copy ProfitCenter.Offset(1, -2)
                    ProfitCenter.Offset(-2, 0).Clear

        Set ProfitCenter = .FindNext(ProfitCenter)

Loop While (Not ProfitCenter Is Nothing) And ProfitCenter.Address <> firstaddress

        End If

End With

'In column (3) I want to select ProfitCenterName cell "Coupon : 20 Yards $25(303)"
'extract only the name of the ProfitCenterName "20 Yards $25(303)"
'Then place the ProfitCenterName "20 Yards $25(303)" into Column(2)
'delete the original cell in column(3)"Coupon : 20 Yards $25(303)"

With ActiveSheet.Columns(3)

    Set Coupontype = .find(What:="Closed Date/Time", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

        CouponName = Right(ProfitCenterName, Len(ProfitCenterName) - 9)

            If Not Coupontype Is Nothing Then
                firstaddress = Coupontype.Address

                    Do
                        Coupontype.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Coupontype.Offset(1, -1)
                        Coupontype.Offset(-1, 0).Clear

    Set Coupontype = .FindNext(Coupontype)

Loop While (Not Coupontype Is Nothing) And Coupontype.Address <> firstaddress

            End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the text `**Coupon : 20 Yards $25(303)**` in row 2?

Comment: The Coupon Type differs and is always in column(3) above the "Closed Date/Time" cell, this is why i used a offset to get the location of the cell.  The Profit Center Name is above the coupon type. the problem i have is that, it depends on how many transactions there were for the coupon. We have multiple Profit Centers which have different coupons. so there X amount of coupons and X amount different coupons in each Profit Center. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ProfitCenterName = Right(ProfitCenterName, Len(ProfitCenterName) - 16)` throw an error because **`ProfitCenterName` was empty** when you start working with it, you should have use something like `ProfitCenterName = ProfitCenter.Offset(-2, 0)`
2. You could do both string extractions in the same loop, take a look at the result.
3. I changed `ProfitCenter.Offset(-2, 0).Copy ProfitCenter.Offset(1, -2)` to `ProfitCenter.Offset(1, -2) = ProfitCenter.Offset(-2, 0)` which is far more efficient!  
   When working with multiple cells Range, you just have to add the `.Value` *(which is implicit for one cell Range)* at the of both sides to accomplish the same

---

Here is your code revised (I just changed `ProfitCenterName` to `fCell` for readabilty):

```
Sub CopyDataFrCellAndPlaceInCellNext()

Dim fCell As Range, _
    FirstAddress As String, _
    ProfitCenterName As String, _
    CouponName As String

With ActiveSheet.Columns(3)
    Set fCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Closed Date/Time", _
                                    After:=ActiveCell, _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = fCell.Address
        Do
            ProfitCenterName = fCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value2
            Debug.Print ProfitCenterName 
            Debug.Print Len(ProfitCenterName)
            ProfitCenterName = Trim(Right(ProfitCenterName, Len(ProfitCenterName) - 16))
            CouponName = fCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value2
            CouponName = Trim(Right(CouponName, Len(CouponName) - 9))
            fCell.Offset(1, -2) = ProfitCenterName
            fCell.Offset(1, -1) = CouponName
            fCell.Offset(-2, 0).Clear
            fCell.Offset(-1, 0).Clear

            Set fCell = .FindNext(fCell)
        Loop While (Not fCell Is Nothing) And fCell.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error "Run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument with this line:ProfitCenterName = Trim(Right(ProfitCenterName, Len(ProfitCenterName) - 16))

Comment: What is the value of `Len(ProfitCenterName)`? And `ProfitCenterName`?

Comment: Im not sure what you are talking about? i am very new to vba, and have been recording macros and using samples from other codes similar to what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: When the line is yellow, put the mouse on `Len(..` for a few instants and the value should appear! Do the same for `ProfitCenterName`. Take a look at these : http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html and http://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/ , it'll save you hours of coderage ;) And once you have activated the Immediate Window change the code to new edit! ;)

Comment: @Lisa : Where are you at on this?

Comment: I keep getting error. I commented out the ProfitCenterName = Trim(Right (profitCenterName... And the code is doing almost what i want. The problem is ProfitCntrName is  2cells above the ClosedDate after all coupons have been totaled for the named ProfitCenter. I did not take in account the CouponTotal.  See the order is like this 
ProfitCenter: CopperOak (1) 
Coupon: 2 for 1 
Closed Date/Time
11-02-2015
11-02-2015
11-02-2015
Coupon Total 
Coupon: Buy 1 get 1 
Closed Date/Time
11-02-2015
11-02-2015
Coupon Total
ProfitCenter: Sunrise (2)
Coupon: Free Drink
Closed Date/Time
11-09-2015

Comment: would it be better to write an if statement

Comment: Nope I think I got it, just google this : how to use immediate window in VBA. And tell me what the 2 `Debug.Print` display in the immediate window, I'd be able to finish the code knowing that

Comment: R3uK  Profit Center : Copper Oak(6)
 29 
Coupon Total
 12

Comment: R3uK Stepping through using F8, the code works 1st time around. As the loop starts again from next Closed Date/Time,-1 CouponName, -2 CouponTotal. The reports will continue this order until there is No more coupons for this particular Profit Center. Then the order is: ClosedDate/Time, -1 CouponName, -2 ProfitCenterName,-3 ProfitCenterTotal, -4 CouponTotal. Then the order begins again, -1 CouponName, -2 CouponTotal etc.

Comment: The next time it runs through the value for ProfitCenterName= "Coupon Total"